# iOS app saving voice notes in database

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, voice-recording

i am making an application in #iOS where the user can record his message using an application. now i want to save this message in the database and retrieve it so that the other users also can listen to this message.

right now i am saving it like this:

```
//audio file save
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"audioFile.aac"];  // Where ext is the audio format extension you have recorded your sound
[player.data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]
```

i can save the file locally. how can i save it so that other users can access it to through the application??

how can i save the voice notes generated on the iPhone to remote data base??

Comment: You can do this with cloudkit.

Comment: you have to upload the voices notes to a server

Answer (score 0):

You can store your voice audio using `NSData` or save locally see below code.

```
NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:audioData forKey:@"reccordingAudio"];
```

To retrieve and play.

```
NSData *audioData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"reccordingAudio"];
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:audioData error:nil];
[player setDelegate:self];
[player play];
```

Note: implement `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` method accordingly